# Is machine learning used much in GIS?

Tags: gps, land-classification, machine-learning, data-mining

I'm new to GIS. Is machine learning used much in this field, and where?

I'm investigating a job opportunity with a mapping company working on traffic awareness. My background is in supervised machine learning (in text classification) and some use of Hadoop, and they assure me that my skills would be appropriate. I've been interested in GPS and GIS for some time, but I want to make sure that my machine learning skills (which I've invested in heavily -- including an MS degree) would be put to good use.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more regarding your land-cover and data-mining tags and how they relate to machine learning.  Within most remote sensing/GIS applications the method of supervised classification are used for created land-cover coverages.

Comment: I added those tags almost randomly. The 'land-classification' tag was the only one that had the word 'classification', which is related to supervised machine learning.

Comment: Have you looked into [pattern recognition](http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Recognition-Fourth-Sergios-Theodoridis/dp/1597492728)?

Answer (score 5):

I do not really see the applicability of Machine Learning with GPS data. However, I utilize these type of modeling techniques on spatial/GIS databases for a large variety of applications. I would imagine that, in fact, these skills would be highly valued indeed.

Methods encompassing supervised and unsupervised data mining, machine learning and nonparamertic modeling can be used in a large variety of spatially related questions including: landcover classification, event clustering, nonlinear inference of spatial process, etc... In addition, given your familiarity with these methods, I would not underestimate your capacity for implementing other types of statistical modeling including spatial statistics.